# NSButton does not call its action

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nsbutton

I am having a little trouble with NSButton's action. I programmatically create a button ...

```
let continueButton = NSButton(title: "Continue", target: self, action: #selector(self.continueButtonClicked))
```

... to call this function:

```
@objc func continueButtonClicked() {
    print("continueButtonClicked")
}
```

However, `continueButtonClicked` is never called and the button appears to be disabled. I've tried enabling it, but that didn't do the trick.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it turns out, the button did call the action, but it only reacted after a few seconds of pressing on it. I managed to figure out that the reason for that was an NSClickGestureReckognizer that I had on the button's superview. Disabling it for the time the button is shown fixed the issue for me.

I hope this helps someone experiencing similar issues.

Comment: "reacted after a few seconds of pressing on it" sounds like you're not in the main thread.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to include sender information in the method. The following code should work and is compatible with Swift 4.

```
let continueButton = NSButton(title: "Continue", target: self, action: #selector(self.continueButtonClicked(_:)))

@objc func continueButtonClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
    print("Continue button clicked")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is great! I immediately adopted it. However, it wasn't the fix for my particular problem.

Comment: Thanks @JanKaiser, sorry it wasn’t what you needed but I’m glad to see you found the solution! :)